# Flattening 3D list of words to 2D

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

I have a pandas column with text strings. For simplicity ,lets assume I have a column with two strings.

```
s=["How are you. Don't wait for me",  "this is all fine"]
```

I want to get something like this:

```
[["How", "are","you"],["Don't", "wait", "for", "me"],["this","is","all","fine"]]
```

Basically take each sentence of a document and tokenism into list of words. So finally I need list of list of string.

I tried using a map like below:

```
nlp=spacy.load('en')
def text_to_words(x):
    """ This function converts sentences in a text to a list of words

    """

    global log_txt
    x=re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", x.strip())
    txt_to_words= [str(doc).replace(".","").split(" ") for doc in nlp(x).sents]

    #log_txt=log_txt.extend(txt_to_words)

    return txt_to_words
```

The nlp from spacy is used to split a string of text into list of sentences.

```
log_txt=list(map(text_to_words,s))

log_txt
```

But this as you know would put all of the result from both the documents into another list

```
[[['How', 'are', 'you'], ["Don't", 'wait', 'for', 'me']],
 [['this', 'is', 'all', 'fine']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a nested list comprehension. Additionally, you can get rid of punctuation using `re.sub`.

```
import re

data = ["How are you. Don't wait for me",  "this is all fine"]
words = [
    re.sub([^a-z\s], '', j.lower()).split() for i in data for j in nlp(i).sents
]
```

Or,

```
words = []
for i in data:
    ... # do something here
    for j in nlp(i).sents:
        words.append(re.sub([^a-z\s], '', j.lower()).split())
```

Comment: This is good. However I need to remove multi blank spaces into one before I convert a text into sentence. That is why I used re.sub("\s\s+" , " ", x.strip()) before passing it into nlp(x).sents.

Comment: @Baktaawar That's up to you. This is a good starting point, so feel free to change it as you need ;)

Comment: no i meant in list comprehension if I have to do some change to string coming out of for i loop above before passing to for j loop, is there a way?

Comment: @Baktaawar There is. You may find it easier to customise by writing a loop. See my edit?

Comment: yeah in loop I know. I was thinking if in list comprehension itself we can do something. Like when I used map I was able to add that since I send one value of column at a time to the mapper function. as shown above.

Comment: @Baktaawar You can replace `nlp(i).sents` with `nlp(re.sub(...)).sents` in the list comp, but it hinders readability, so I won't recommend that.

Comment: yeah i think so too. I think loop is what I would have to use since its getting complicated and not very readable

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way for list comprehension.
You can first join the strings with a period '.' and split them again.

```
[x.split() for x in '.'.join(s).split('.')]
```

It will give the desired result.

```
[["How", "are","you"],["Don't", "wait", "for", "me"],["this","is","all","fine"]]
```

For Pandas dataframes, you may get an object, and hence a list of lists after `tolist` function in return. Just extract the first element.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

def splitwords(s):
    s1 = [x.split() for x in '.'.join(s).split('.')]
    return s1

df = pd.DataFrame(s)
result = df.apply(splitwords).tolist()[0]
```

Again, it will give you the preferred result.

Hope it helps ;)